# Remove file path from mac terminal prompt

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

I am trying to get rid of the the file path that shows up in the command prompt in mac terminal.

Example: `superuser@x-160-94-176-201:[~/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/]$`

If you have longer directory names you will end up loosing the entire line. I know in cshrc I can do this, infact I have edited .cshrc in my ubuntu box to make this change.

```
  if ( $?tcsh ) then
    #set prompt="%n@%m (%/) % "
    set prompt="[%n@%m %c]% "
    #set prompt="%n@%B%m%b (%B%~%b) % "
    set prompt2 = "%R loop: "
    set prompt3 = "oops\041 %R (y|n|e)? "
```

I run bash on my mac and but I tried putting set prompt in my `bash_profile` but it didn't have any impact.

Answer (score 2):

On bash (and other `*sh`-style shells) you set the prompt by setting the environment variable `PS1`.

For example, setting it to

```
% PS1=`hostname`':\W> '
```

Gives you a prompt:

```
host:pwd>
```

where `host` is your host name (as returned by the command `hostname`), and `pwd` is the last component of your path.

Look at `man bash` and search for `PROMPTING` for all the details, including how to do bold characters, include the time, and so on.

`zsh` (which is a nice shell) has more extensive support for fancy prompts.